# How large is a deflated zlib object?

Tags: zlib

I am trying to to identify the size of a deflated zlib blob. In specific, I am deflating an object and shortly afterwards another deflated blob is in this file. I want to know how many files the deflated blob takes before moving to the next. Is there a way to identify this number of bytes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
When you assign the value for strm.avail_in, you capture the inputted bytes as follows

```
input_len = strm.avail_in = NUMBER_OF_BYTES_READ_FROM_FILE_OR_STREAM;
```

Then when you run this:

```
ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
```

It should update the strm.avail_in value with the number of remaining bytes from that iteration of inflation. The difference between strm.avail_in and the input_len value is the number of deflated bytes read in that iteration. So, something like this:

```
read_bytes = input_len - strm.avail_in;
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.